# Output all the results of SELECT statements in a WHILE as one whole

Tags: php, sql, output, mariadb

I have a procedure that loops through multiple dates of rows and gets the average of each day. It looks like this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE d_counter int DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE d_difference int DEFAULT DATEDIFF(enddate, startdate);
    IF d_difference > 0 THEN
            WHILE d_counter <= d_difference DO
                 SELECT id, ROUND(AVG(Temperature), 1) AS 'avgt', ROUND(AVG(Humidity), 1) AS 'avgh', Timestamp FROM 
                    (SELECT * FROM temperature_room2
                    WHERE timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL d_counter DAY
                    AND timestamp <= CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL d_counter DAY) AS A;
```

Ignore the lack of END here, it won't copy for some reason.

When I run this procedure the output will looks like this:
[image]

So I have two questions:
When I try to use a while loop in PHP with $row = $msqli_fetch_assoc($result), will this still work?

Second question:
If no, how do I output the results as one 'table'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only have 1 id per day? If not, where do these oddball non-sequenced ids come from? This should all be done in one query aggregating per day, doing it this way is a touch insane, especially when you add in the superfluous subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this in a simple query. There's no reason to have procedure, looping, subqueries and all this other nonsense:

```
 SELECT date(timestamp) datestamp, ROUND(AVG(Temperature), 1) AS 'avgt', ROUND(AVG(Humidity), 1) AS 'avgh'
 FROM temperature_room2
 GROUP BY datestamp;
```

I suspect your oddball id field is just outputting a random id from the table that happens to fall into the day for that record since you are aggregating but fail to include the non-aggregated fields like `id` in a `GROUP BY`. Any other RDBMS would flat out reject this query with an error, but mysql gives you plenty of rope so you can hang yourself and half your organization.

Comment: You are amazing. Fiddled with it for quite a few hours (I'm quite new to SQL) and this helped me a lot. I probably will get it working now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Just try to adjust your head over to set-based thinking instead of procedural. There is VERY rarely a need to loop through a table or a need to execute a sql statement inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a php while loop or a for each loop is what you are looking for.  It will display results for each row here is an example of both.

While Loop

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    // output data of each row
$var1 = $row['YourDBtableName1'];
$var2 = $row['YourDBtableName2'];
$var3 = $row['YourDBtableName3'];
$var4 = $row['YourDBtableName4'];
$var5 = $row['YourDBtableName5'];
$var6 = $row['YourDBtableName6'];
$var7 = $row['YourDBtableName7'];
//create your Table or div and echo the results. It will create the table for each row.
echo $var1;
echo $var2;
echo $var3;
echo $var4;
echo $var5;
echo $var6;
echo $var7;}}
```

And your ForEach Loop.

```
if ($results->num_rows > 0){
foreach ($results as $res){ 
$var1 = $res['YourDBtableName1'];
$var2 = $res['YourDBtableName2'];
$var3 = $res['YourDBtableName3'];
$var4 = $res['YourDBtableName4'];
$var5 = $res['YourDBtableName5'];
$var6 = $res['YourDBtableName6'];
$var7 = $res['YourDBtableName7'];
//create your Table or div and echo the results. It will create the table for each row.
echo $var1;
echo $var2;
echo $var3;
echo $var4;
echo $var5;
echo $var6;
echo $var7;}}
```

Comment: You can also customize each row with some html and css